# Does this login system function need to replace any of my current code and where do I place it?

Tags: php, javascript, session, cookies

At the moment this is how my login and logoff system works:

When a user logs in, it stores in their details in a $_SESSION in a script known as member.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }
```

Then in every script it contains the code below where the sessionlife lasts for 12 hours:

```
 <?php

    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
    ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
    ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
    require_once 'init.php'; 

    session_start();

include(member.php)

    ?>
```

init.php is this below:

```
 <?php
 session_save_path('Session'); 
 ?>
```

Now after 12 hours the next time the user refreshes the page, as the session will be destroyed, it goes to the logoff page:

```
if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
    session_destroy();
    echo "You have been Logged Out | <a href='./home.php'>Home</a>";
}

else {

    echo "You are Not Logged In";

}
```

Obviously if the user clicks on the logout page then it navigates to script above.

But I found out a better way to keep user's logged in and for them to not logout until they log themselves out is with this code below:

```
if (session_exists) continue();
else if (!session_exists AND cookie_exists AND validate_cookie()) {
    login_user_via_cookie();
    continue();
else show_login_page();
```

My question, is first of all where do I place this code, do I replace it with the session_maxlife and all of the ini_set code I set? Do I need to replace any of that code and do I need to change the code I found above to get it working in my script? (My logout page is in a script known as Text4.php)

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

teacherlogin.php page:

```
<?php
/*
file: login.php
authorized (logged in) users must be redirected to a secure page (member.php) or (secure.php)
unauthorized (guests) users have to see the login form
*/

#include the class file and start it.
require_once('session.class.php');
$session = new Session();

#check user's access
if($session->get("auth")) header("location:member.php");

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

// connect to the database
include('member.php');
include('connect.php');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
die();
}

// required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
$teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
$teacherpassword = (isset($_POST['teacherpassword'])) ? $_POST['teacherpassword'] : '';
$loggedIn = false;
$active = true;

if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){
echo "You are already Logged In: <b>{$_SESSION['teacherforename']} {$_SESSION['teachersurname']}</b> | <a href='./menu.php'>Go to Menu</a> | <a href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
else{

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$teacherpassword."rt4"));  

// don't use $mysqli->prepare here
$query = "SELECT TeacherId, TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId, $dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
if ($dbActive == 0) {
$loggedIn = false;
$active = false;
echo "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
}else {
$loggedIn = true;
$active = true;
$_SESSION['teacherid'] = $dbTeacherId;
$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $dbTeacherUsername;
}
}
}

if ($loggedIn == true){
$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $dbTeacherForename;
$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $dbTeacherSurname;
header( 'Location: menu.php' ) ;
die();
}

if (!$loggedIn && $active && isset($_POST)) {
echo "<span style='color: red'>The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again</span>";
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Teacher Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TeacherLoginStyle.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
include('noscript.php');
?>

<h1>TEACHER LOGIN</h1>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" id="teachLoginForm">        
<p>Username</p><p><input type="text" name="teacherusername" /></p>      <!-- Enter Teacher Username-->
<p>Password</p><p><input type="password" name="teacherpassword" /></p>  <!-- Enter Teacher Password--> 
<p><input id="loginSubmit" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

<a href="./forgotpass.php">Forgot Password</a>

</body>

<?php

}

?>
</html>
```

teacherlogout.php page:

```
<?php

require_once('session.class.php');
$session = new Session();

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);


session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">

</head>

<?php

include('member.php');
include('noscript.php');

?>

<body>

<?php

if($session->get("auth")){
session_destroy();
echo "You have been Logged Out | <a href='./home.php'>Home</a>";
}

else {

echo "You are Not Logged In";

}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

member.php page:

```
<?php

/*
file: secure.php, profile.php, member.php
authorized (logged in) users => log them out and show goodbye msg or send them to login.php
unauthorized (guests) users => redirect them to login.php
*/
require_once('session.class.php');
$session = new Session();

#if user is not logged in, he will be sent to the login.php page
#note the (!) sign before the $session, it means if the $session->get("auth") == false
if(!$session->get("auth")) header("location:teacherlogin.php");

#if user is not logged in, he will be sent to the login.php page
#note the (!) sign before the $session, it means if the $session->get("auth") == false
if(!$session->get("auth")) header("location:teacherlogin.php");


//need to the code below in order to store details of teacher that is logged in (needed for queries in other pages)

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherforename'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherforename'] = $_SESSION['teacherforename'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teachersurname'])) {

$_SESSION['teachersurname'] = $_SESSION['teachersurname'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

$userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

}

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

$username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

}

?>
```

Comment: first your code is not well structured, and for the other code you "found" do you have the complete code? because its made using custom functions and you need that function defined

Comment: do you any function which stores session in a cookie?..

Comment: Hi sorry been asleep as I posted this question 2am. I do not have the complete code on the code I found, that was all the code I found, Do you have any idea on how to call this function? I don't have a function which stores session into a cookie. This is why I hope anyone who has dealt with this is able to help me to get the above code to work in my page :)

Comment: @MohdMoe I have made comment above

Comment: @CMB the code you found and you want to implement in your code, uses cookies next to the session to re authenticate the user even after the session is expired, the (Remember me) feature you see in some websites, so is it what are you looking for or you just want a better code wrap to handle session? also do you want the user to remain in your website for 12 hours or forever until he logs out or when he closes his browser? it depends on your needs

Comment: @MohdMoe What I really want is the user to stay logged onto the website until he clicks the log out button or closes the browser. If the user is still logged in then he stays logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Class you can use and edit if you need to:

File **session.class.php**

```
<?php
/*
Simple PHP Session Class:
    a simple class to help managing the Session function in
    php for beginners and it introduces them to OOP where
    they can modify it and add new features and extend its
    functionality (session in database, track users actions,etc)
*/
#Session settings.

#Session cookie lifetime at the user browser. (seconds)
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');

#Read the functions reference below before you change these values.
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',7200);# 2 hours.
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1'); #default PHP value.
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '100'); #default PHP value.

/*====================================================================

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');

    User cookie life time in seconds.
    0 means the cookie wont expire until the user closes the broswer


ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',7200); #default: 1440 (24 mins).

    Session Garbage Collection cleaner (GC). 

    7200(seconds) equals to (2 hours): The GC will try to
    clean session data in the server for (users who logged
    out, closed the browser AND users who are inactive for
    more than that time) however the clean function does
    not run directly, read the next block for more explaination.

    PHP manual:
        session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of
        seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage'
        and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may
        occur during session start
        (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).


ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1'); #default PHP value (1).
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '100'); #default PHP value (100).

    Garbage Collection (GC) Settings:
    PHP manual:
        session.gc_divisor coupled with
        session.gc_probability defines the probability
        that the gc (garbage collection) process is started
        on every session initialization. The probability is
        calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor
        e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC
        process starts on each request.
        session.gc_divisor defaults to 100.  
====================================================================*/

/*
    HOW TO USE:
    - include the session file in all your files and call the session object
    require_once('session.class.php');
    $session = new Session();


    GET SESSION ID:
    - $session->sid;
      @return type (string)
      @example:
      echo $session->sid;

    GENEREATE NEW SESSION ID:
    - $session->re();
      @return type (string)
      #note: returns the value of the new session id.
      @example:
      $sid = $session->sid;
      $new_sid = $session->re();
      echo "My Session ID is: {$sid} but I got a new one now: {$new_sid};

    ASSIGN NEW SESSION VALUE:
    - $session->set($key,$value);
      @return type (void)
      @examples:
        $session->set("name","foo bar");
        $session->set("age",24);
        $session->set("auth",TRUE);

    GET SESSION VALUE:
    - $session->get($key);
      @return type (boolean, int, string, array).
      #note: returns FALSE if the value is not set
      @examples:
      echo $session->get("name");
      if($session->get("auth")) echo "hello authorized user!";

      if(($age = $session->get("age")) > 21)
      echo "your age is {$age}, you can drive!";

    DELETE SESSION VALUE:
    - $session->delete($key);
      @return type (void);
      @example
      $session->delete("age");

    DESTROY SESSION
    - $session->destroy();
      @return type (void);
*/
/*==================================================================*/
class Session{
    public $sid;
    public function __construct() {
        @session_start();
        $this->sid = session_id();
    }
    public function re(){
        @session_regenerate_id();
        $this->sid = session_id();
        return $this->sid;
    }
    public function set($key, $val) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $val;
        return true;
    }

    public function get($key) {
        if ( isset($_SESSION[$key]) ) {
            return $_SESSION[$key];
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function delete($key) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }

    public function destroy() {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
    }
}            
?>
```

**FILE: member.php**

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /*
    file: secure.php, profile.php, member.php
    authorized (logged in) users => log them out and show goodbye msg or send them to login.php
    unauthorized (guests) users => redirect them to login.php
    */
    require_once('session.class.php');
    $session = new Session();

    #if user is not logged in, he will be sent to the login.php page
    #note the (!) sign before the $session, it means if the $session->get("auth") == false
    if(!$session->get("auth")) header("location:teacherlogin.php");

    echo "hello, you are logged in";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "username: ".$session->get("teacherusername");
    echo "<br />";
    echo "teacherid: ".$session->get("teacherid");
    echo "<br />";
    echo "active status: ".$session->get("active") ? "Active" : "Not Active";
    echo "<br />";
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Log out</a>";

?>
```

**FILE : logout.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('session.class.php');
$session = new Session();

if($session->get("auth")){
    session_destroy();
    $msg = "You have been Logged Out | <a href='./home.php'>Home</a>";
}else{
    $msg = "You were not logged in, so you cant logout";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Menu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">

</head>

<?php
include('noscript.php');
?>

<body>
    <?= $msg ? $msg : '' ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**FILE: login.php**

```
<?php
/*
file: login.php
authorized (logged in) users must be redirected to a secure page (member.php) or (secure.php)
unauthorized (guests) users have to see the login form
*/

#include the class file and start it.
require_once('session.class.php');
$session = new Session();

#check user's access
if($session->get("auth"))header("location:member.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php

// connect to the database
@include('connect.php');
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
}

// required variables (make them explciit no need for foreach loop)
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $teacherusername = (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) ? $_POST['teacherusername'] : '';
    $teacherpassword = md5(md5("g3f".$_POST['teacherpassword']."rt4"));  

    // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
    $query = "SELECT TeacherId, TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Active FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ? AND TeacherPassword = ? LIMIT 1";
    // prepare query
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$teacherusername,$teacherpassword);
    // execute query
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherId, $dbTeacherForename,$dbTeacherSurname,$dbTeacherUsername,$dbTeacherPassword, $dbActive);

    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        if ($teacherusername == $dbTeacherUsername && $teacherpassword == $dbTeacherPassword) {
            if ($dbActive == 0) {
                $error = "You Must Activate Your Account from Email to Login";
            }else{
                $session->set('auth',TRUE);
                $session->set('active',TRUE);
                $session->set('teacherid',$dbTeacherId);
                $session->set('teacherusername',$dbTeacherUsername);
                header('Location: member.php') ;
            }
        }else{
            //password and username dont match
                $error = "The Username or Password that you Entered is not Valid. Try Entering it Again";
        }
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, I tried to edit the code you gave me and apply it into my php script but it is not working. When I try to open up the login page it keeps saying on the browser page `the page is being redirect properly`. The cookies are enables and I wanted to know if you can look at my code update in my question to see what I am doing incorrectly. The session.class.php page is the same code as the one you have showed me

Comment: The problem would be not checking session probably in one of the functions/pages, so for example the session starts in login.php but it does not get checked in member.php, you will have to track the code, first try the code i added for the `login.php` page, and then do the same in `member.php`

Comment: Ok, I have tried your code you entered in `login.php` and `member.php` and it actually displays the login form, allows the user to login and then goes on the logout page. So really all that needs to be done if you don't mind is show how to implement your code into my code (under the "UPDATE" in my question) so that it fully works. it is so that I can update future scripts with the complete code. In the `member.php` page am I able to keep the `$SESSION` variables I currently have in the script?

Comment: Also what about the current if statement in `teacherlogin.php` and `teacherlogout.php` page `if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){` this used to check if a user was logged in but do I need this now or do I need to remove it? Again if you can implement my code to show the full version, it would really help. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello I have updated my answer again, please use the pages, `login.php` logout.php` `member.php`